# Convert a subquery to a query using Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

```
tblTenant

idTenant   Name
1          Hello
2          World
3          Foo 
4          Bar

tblPhone

idTenant    idPhoneType   PhoneNum
1            23             31445
1            24            43123
1            25            90899
2            23             90937
2            24             34544
4            24             23455
```

Now I want all the tenants Id's who **never** have a **phonetype** of **25.**

```
Output:

idTenant
2
3
4
```

idTenant = 1 is excluded because it has an entry of phonetype = 25

Query I wrote:

```
select * from tblTenant where idTenant not in ( SELECT distinct(idTenant) FROM tblPhone where idPhoneType = 25) ;
```

But I want to write this query using JOINS. Is it possible? Please guide me.

.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    t1.idTenant, t1.Name
FROM tblTenant
LEFT JOIN tblPhone t2
    ON t1.idTenant = t2.idTenant
GROUP BY
    t1.idTenant, t1.Name
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN t2.idPhoneType = 25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 AND
    COUNT(t2.idTenant) > 0;
```

The crux of the above query is that we aggregate over the `tblPhone` by tenant, and assert that phone type 25 never occurs.  Then, we join to `tblTenant` to bring in the actual tenant name.

Comment: Suppose there is one more caveat that if NO entry is present in tblphone then ignore it. I mean I would like the output to have just idTenant 2 and 4. Can you kindly tel me how to achieve it. idTenant 3 has no entry at all in tblPhone so we dont want that. Can I achieve that. Many Thanks!

Comment: I also thought so because of Inner Join but I am seeing those tenants also which does not have entry in tblPhone. So as per example I am seeing 2,3,4

Comment: I might be overlooking something.. :-|

Comment: I feel like fool now. But sir, you were right your original query is returning tenant 2 and 4 only. Sorry for the confusion. I am extremely sorry

Comment: I was just trying to learn both type of query. One with output 2,3,4 and another with output only 2,4

Comment: My update is better IMO because you can remove count from the having clause to view all tenants.

Comment: OK.. got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Left Join` for this -

```
select distinct
    T.idTenant
from tblTenant T
left join tblPhone P on P.idTenant = T.idTenant and P.idPhoneType = 25
where P.idTenant IS NULL
```

Comment: Suppose there is one more caveat that if entry is present in tblphone then ignore it. I mean I would like the output to have just idTenant 2 and 4. Can you kindly tel me how to achieve it. idTenant 3 has no entry at all in tblPhone. Can I achieve that. Many Thanks!

Comment: I think it is not possible without any aggregation. Please check @Tim Biegeleisen answer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am trying to run your query but I am getting different output. Can you kindly visit this link. Am I missing something silly. https://gist.github.com/tnayanam/eb39941c3c484e44360079eb9af1915d

Comment: I have updated above mentioned GIT Link with the actual image of my MySQL WorkBench. Can you kindly review one more time. Also I am working on MySQL (sorry I forgot to mention it before)

Comment: Strange, no idea. Are you using MS SQL Server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166020/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-bhatiaashish).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    CREAte TAble #tblTenant(idTenant INT,Name VARCHAR(10))

    INSERT INTO #tblTenant VALUES(1,'Hello')
    INSERT INTO #tblTenant VALUES(2,'World')
    INSERT INTO #tblTenant VALUES(3,'Foo')
    INSERT INTO #tblTenant VALUES(4,'Bar')

    --SELECT * from #tblTenant

    CREATE TABLE #tblPhone(idTenant INT,idPhoneType INT,PhoneNum BIGINT)

    INSERT INTO #tblPhone vALUES(1,23,31445)
    INSERT INTO #tblPhone vALUES(1,24,43123)
    INSERT INTO #tblPhone vALUES(1,25,90899)
    INSERT INTO #tblPhone vALUES(2,23,90937)
    INSERT INTO #tblPhone vALUES(2,24,34544)
    INSERT INTO #tblPhone vALUES(4,4,23455)

    --select * from #tblPhone

    select t.idTenant from #tblTenant t
    LEFT JOIN #tblPhone p on t.idTenant=p.idTenant and p.idPhoneType=25
    WHERE p.idTenant IS NULL

    DROP TABLE #tblPhone

    DROP TABLE #tblTenant
```